# Newest tab on mobile shows last editor, instead of OP

Tags: bug, mobile-web, newest-questions

There is a minor inconsistency in the newest tab, between the mobile and the full site.

In the mobile site it shows the person that did the last edit (or who posted the last answer) - just like in the "active" tab

[image]

but in the full site is shows the OP.

[image]

This seems like an (admittedly really minor) bug to me...

Comment: @Tim yea it seems like the same issue (although that one is from August 2012)